# Why am I getting an "ArrayIndexoutofBound" error in my Java program?

Tags: java, exception, workflow, indexoutofboundsexception, value-of

need to understand flow of following progarm.
what should be the output? 
when i compile this program i got "ArrayIndexoutofBound" error.

```
public class test {

   public static void main(String args[]) { 

      Integer intObj=Integer.valueOf(args[args.length-1]);
      int i = intObj.intValue();

      if(args.length > 1) 
         System.out.println(i);
      if(args.length > 0)
         System.out.println(i - 1);
      else 
         System.out.println(i - 2);
   }
}
```

Comment: Easy to see how this would happen: args array doesn't have any values if you don't have command line arguments.

Comment: Are you entering any [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)? You'll get that exception if you don't have any.

Comment: Based on the error and the code, I think that you must provide at least 1 command line argument. The ArrayIndexOutOfBounds happens when you fail to do that. The program should run fine when you have provided one.

Comment: an empty array has length 0, and `args[-1]` is undefined.

Comment: if I am passing args[] without any command line argument then by default size of array value will be 0 ??

Comment: @Raxit Yes, but in the amount of time it took for you to get a reply, you could have found out for yourself :P

Comment: :D thanks....keep that in mind..!!

Answer (score 0):

**"ArrayIndexoutofBound"** :Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

So probably you are not passing any command line argument. So `args.Lenght` return 0.

So here :

```
Integer intObj=Integer.valueOf(args[0-1]);
```

**Index** is negative thats why JVM throw **"ArrayIndexoutofBound"**

Comment: Integer intObj=Integer.valueOf(args[10-1]);                           output : 9                                                        with error arrayIndexOutOfBound.

Answer (score 0):

Add some input check if some input exist before Integer.valueOf(args[args.length-1]); And add some input information to execution.